# Block user features through Group Policy

Tags: windows-xp, gpedit

I have a Windows XP system. How can I block the limited users to access everything other than just the installed applications?

The administrator should get all the features.

Comment: "everything other than the installed applications"? Can you clarify what that means?

Comment: May be in the list
on start menu they will have only microsoft office, google chrome or firefox, or IE, 
they wont have acces to my computer, Will have a folder in desktop to save files. also, need to block some internet sires to those users. all this for limited user or a group of users.

Answer (score 1):

Use Local Group Policy Editor to set a Group Policy for your local computer. You can allow access to defined applications, limit access to directories, programs, registry settings etc.
Group policies are what they use in large corporate environments to lock down computers connected to their networks.